# PHP/SQL get Field of current line

Tags: php, sql

sorry for the post name I have a hard time explaining on one sentence what my problem is all about.

I have a table created like that:

```
CREATE TABLE Table(id INT, account_id INT, time BIGINT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

Let's say after some adds my table looks like that:

Table

```
id | account_id | time
   |            |
 0 |       NULL | 1000000
   |            |
 2 |        698 | 1000000
   |            |
 3 |       NULL | 1000000
```

In my PHP code, I have a function `API_getAccountId($id)`. I'm executing queries in PHP, so how can I, in my PHP code, execute something like:

```
UPDATE Table SET account_id = API_getAccountId(/*current line id field*/) WHERE acccount_id IS NULL
```

I'm looking for a way to set every null account_id to API_getAccountId($id) where $id is the id in the lane containing account_id ; it should update the database this way:

```
id |          account_id | time
   |                     |
 0 | API_getAccountId(0) | 1000000
   |                     |
 2 |                 698 | 1000000
   |                     |
 3 | API_getAccountId(3) | 1000000
```

Hope I was clear, thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this in two steps, because you need to execute your PHP function `API_getAccountId($id)` for each row. Since each query you execute is executed on MySQL, you cannot run a PHP function there.

First of all you need to get all the rows. For that, you should select the columns and rows in question and run your PHP function over that result set:

```
$query = 'SELECT id, account_id FROM Table WHERE account_id IS NULL;';
$result = //Your MySQL magic;

$newIds = [];

while ($result->fetch() as $row) {
    $newIds[$row['id']] = API_getAccountId($row['id']);
}
```

With the newly generated array you can update your database:

```
foreach($newIds as $id => $account_id) {

    $query = 'UPDATE Table SET account_id = ? WHERE id = ?';
    $yourSqlMagic->prepare($query);
    $yourSqlMagic->execute([$id, $account_id]);
}
```

`$yourSqlMagic` refers to the way you execute your queries in PHP. It might differ from the way i presented it here, but you should get the idea.

Comment: Thanks I'm looking at it!